# Sharepoint search _MM.DD Issues

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, search

I have a site set up for users to search for documents. As of late we have had an issue with files not showing up in search. After few days I have narrowed it down it files that have "_MM.DD" in the file name dont show

"1234-1234567_MM.DD.YYY_label.pdf"

If I change "." to "_" it works or change to "_DD.MM.YYY".

seems to be the exact combo of "_MM.DD". before i start renaming hunderends of files was hoping someone might know why and how to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain you can get it to work by changing "." to "_" or changing to "_DD.MM"?

“_MM.DD” or “_DD.MM” should be identified as the same format by SharePoint. Only ISO 8601-compatible datetime formats are supported in queries, such as “YYYY-MM-DD”.

Per my test, what is returned in the search result is based on what keyword you have used.

For example:

1. If you search for “1234-1234567” or “1234” or “_label”, it should return all documents.
   [image]
2. if you search for the middle part “*MM.DD.YYY*” with punctuation, no matter what the combination is, it will always return 0 result. But if you are using modern search, it will actually return related results in the search query suggestions.
   [image]

Here’s your reference:

[Keyword Query Language (KQL) syntax reference.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/keyword-query-language-kql-syntax-reference)

Comment: sorry was not clear enough. it is the actual letter combo that is used not the date. the file is a template file so it is title "1234-1234567_MM.DD.YYY_label.pdf"

Comment: @Jeffha77 That’s ok. “xx.yy.zzzz” won’t be identified as date as well.